# How to get next row value from Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, yii, sqlyog

I want to get (select) the next row value from MySql query using SQLYog, with 
 the same id_voyage_order?

Example :

```
id_timesheet | id_voyage_order | Duration
----------------------------------------

1            | 106             | 0.00
2            | 106             | 24.00
3            | 210             | 12.00
4            | 106             | 12.00
5            | 210             | 24.00
```

i want to select it and make in View file Yii based on the same id_voyage order become like this and set the Duration of the last record become 0 :

```
id_timesheet | id_voyage_order | Duration
1.           | 106             | 24.00
2.           | 106             | 12.00
4.           | 106             | 0.00
```

Comment: At this siteyou are expected to try a query of your own first, then ask for help if stuck. For example does the following query do what you need? *select id_timesheet, id_voyage_order, Duration from that_table order by duration DESC where id_voyage_order = 106* nb: it is always helpful to provide table names.

Comment: ty @Used_By_Already :) 

SELECT id_timesheet, id_voyage_order, Duration 
FROM timesheet
WHERE  id_voyage_order ='106'

then how to make the condition get next row values?

Comment: i am sory, i've repaired the id @Strawberry

Comment: how about for the query not only for id_voyage _order = 106? @Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance:

```
SELECT a.id_timesheet
     , a.id_voyage_order
     , COALESCE(b.duration,0) duration
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT x.*
             , MAX(y.id_timesheet) previous
          FROM my_table x 
          JOIN my_table y 
            ON y.id_voyage_order = x.id_voyage_order 
           AND y.id_timesheet < x.id_timesheet 
         GROUP 
            BY x.id_timesheet
      ) b
     ON b.previous = a.id_timesheet
  WHERE a.id_voyage_order = 106;
```